# Catching Errors and Error Pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception, custom-error-pages

I want to add a friendly error page to my application that would say a text like, "Oops some thing went wrong". I want the error page to be displayed automatically for every page of my application in the even of an exception. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply enable custom errors in web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On">

</customErrors>
```

and the `~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx` view will be rendered on unhandled error (assuming your controller is decorated with the [`[HandleError]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx) attribute).

Then you can have more fine grained control and different views for different exceptions:

```
[HandleError(
    View = "~/Views/Errors/Custom.aspx", 
    ExceptionType = typeof(SomeCustomException))]
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. I am new to MVC 2 so where in web.config would I put <customErrors> in? Would it be under <system.web>? Also do I create the Error.aspx file or would the system generate it? Thanks.

Comment: @Derek, yes, `<customErrors>` goes inside `<system.web>`. `Error.aspx` is normally created by the default template inside the `~/Views/Shared` folder but if it doesn't exist you might create it.

Comment: Darin, I did what you told me. I put the [HandleError] on the class. To test code, I am throwing an exception in one of my functions. When I run the code it does not show the error page (~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx). Am I doing something wrong? I am new MVC so I apologize. Thanks again.

Comment: Dari, the standard yellow error page and say that the user is not catching the exception.

Comment: @Derek, ensure that you have set `<system.web><customErrors mode="On" /></system.web>` in your web.config and that the controller throwing the exception is decorated with the `[HandleError]` attribute. Normally that's all you need to  have the custom `~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx` page show. Also make sure that the error you are seeing in the yellow screen is not related somehow to rendering the `Error.aspx` view. For example if this view uses the masterpage and inside this masterpage you are trying to access to some information that is not available you might get exceptions.

Comment: Darin, [HandleError] attribute is on the controller class and yes I am using the master page and that did not occur to me. I have fixed that and it is now working. Thanks for the help. =)